R optim() Not Converging to Target R-squared Value
I'm trying to wrap my head around the optim() function in R. Therefore I tried to optimize two beta parameters (beta1 and beta2) in a linear model so that the resulting R-squared value matches a specified target (e.g., 0.1). I've written the following code in R:
generate_data <- function(n_obs = 100, beta_params = c(2, 3), noise_sd = 1) {
  # Extract beta parameters
  beta1 <- beta_params[1]
  beta2 <- beta_params[2]
  
  # Generate predictors X1 and X2
  X1 <- rnorm(n_obs)  # Normally distributed predictor 1
  X2 <- rnorm(n_obs)  # Normally distributed predictor 2
  
  # Generate response variable Y with added Gaussian noise
  Y <- beta1 * X1 + beta2 * X2 + rnorm(n_obs, mean = 0, sd = noise_sd)
  
  # Return data as a data frame
  data <- data.frame(X1 = X1, X2 = X2, Y = Y)
  return(data)
}

lm_r2 <- function(beta_params, target_r2, n_obs = 100, noise_sd = 1) {
  # Generate data with current beta parameters
  data <- generate_data(n_obs = n_obs, beta_params = beta_params, noise_sd = noise_sd)
  
  # Fit a linear model
  model <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data)
  
  # Calculate R-squared
  actual_r2 <- summary(model)$r.squared
  
  # Return the squared difference from the target R-squared
  (actual_r2 - target_r2)^2
}

# Define the target R-squared
target_r2 <- 0.1

# Use optim to minimize the lm_r2 function
result <- optim(
  par = c(1, 1),  # Initial guesses for beta1 and beta2
  fn = function(beta_params) lm_r2(beta_params, target_r2 = target_r2),
  method = "L-BFGS-B"
)


# Extract optimized parameters
optimized_beta1 <- result$par[1]
optimized_beta2 <- result$par[2]

# Print results
cat("Optimized beta1:", optimized_beta1, "\n")
cat("Optimized beta2:", optimized_beta2, "\n")

# check if the optimized parameters result in the target R-squared
data <- generate_data(n_obs = 100, beta_params = c(optimized_beta1, optimized_beta2))
model <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = data)

summary(model)$r.squared

When I run this code, the optim() function completes, and I get optimized beta1 and beta2 values. However, when I use these optimized parameters to generate new data and compute the R-squared, the result is not close to my target R-squared (e.g., 0.1).
Observations:

For larger target R-squared values (e.g., 0.8), the solution seems to work better but not perfectly.
For smaller target R-squared values (e.g., 0.1), the discrepancy between the target and computed R-squared is larger.
The optimization runs without errors, but it doesn't converge to the desired result.


But you are using new randomly generated numbers each time, so the R squared will be different each time, even for the same set of parameters. I'm struggling to see why you would expect the R squared to be the same.

Well R-squared ist still a function of the estimated coefficients in the linear model. Even if I run the model with different numbers the R squared should be ruffly the same, righ? Or in other words if I would do this 1000 times, the avarage coefficient should result in the desired R-squared.

the problem is that you are not in control of the random noise. It is always possible that rnorm(n_obs, mean = 0, sd = noise_sd) will generate atypical values that end up resulting in the target R squared even when the beta_params aren't quite right. You then generate data using these not-quite-right beta_params and a new sample of random data that will give you a different R squared. Yes, the law of large numbers might apply eventually, but that doesn't help you find a random sample with the correct n_obs and a target R squared.

The way round this is to generate your random data once, and feed it in to the parameter-tuning function. Use the output of optim to modify the original random data.

I see, thanks! To give some context I wanted to use this approach to define beta parameters in a mutilevel setting. Given that variance decomposition in multilevel modeling can become rather complex when adjusting parameters at different levels, I've been attempting to approximate the marginal R-squared value through simulation. This was just a test. Do you have any suggestion how to approcha this better?

Chi-squared is usually a much more reliable metric for quality of fit than R^2. And ANOVA allows you a much more quantitative estimation of how much each parameter in a model contributes to fitting the data.

The reasoning behind  why I want to do this is ranther complex, as it relates to some other research. In short, in a multilevel context I want to be able to have some "controll" over the the impact of different parameters on the explained variance (R-squared) I'm not interessted in the quality of fit per se.
